# Is there an iOS Android Support Library equivalent?

Tags: ios

What is iOS' equivalent of Android Support Library?  I'm currently not aware of one what would be the reasons not to use it aside from file bloat?

Comment: your question is not clear. what you tried and what you need

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik Android provides a Support Library for enabling new features on devices running older versions of Android. Is there such a mechanism on iOS. What are the disadvantages off using the Android library to do that?

Comment: @StalinKay No there is no equivalent, that goes against apples design. Most of the new features require OS level additions, due to design decisions such as security reasons etc. iOS has a drastically higher install rate of OS's than Android, because of this, it is typically the default behaviour to support the current OS and the previous one.

Comment: @SimonMcLoughlin Thank you for the feedback. Greatly appreciated.